# How to make method arguments visible in StarUML diagrams

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, staruml

I am trying to display the arguments in a sequence diagram using staruml

Is it possible to display the arguments like this?

```
      1: saveResult(int value)
```

Comment: Do you mean is this an adequate way of displaying it, or how do you do it in the specific application, staruml?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Go to Toolbox -> Sequence -> Stimulus.
2. Drag from one object to another to create the stimulus line
3. On the side you should see the Properties for the call
4. In Name put the method name, i.e. saveResult
5. In the Detail section you can specify arguments. Put the arguments there, i.e. int value
6. If the arguments don't appear then change the properties of the Sequence Diagram. Change MessageSignature to NAMEANDTYPE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Try the sequence diagram user manual.](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/docs/user-guide%28en%29/ch05_3.html)